# Navigate to a specific component (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, navigation

I have a **page 1** and a **page 2**. On **page 1** is a specific component. On **page 2** I have a button. After clicking on that button I want to navigate to the position of the specific component on **page 1**.

Is there a legit way to handle this?

By the way I am using GatsbyJS.

Comment: Use [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Gatsby, there is a plugin made for that :)
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-anchor-links/

Else you can just set an id on the component on page 2 and link with `/page2#yourid`